# How to make sure labels in qgis turn up in layout map?

Tags: qgis, labeling, qgis-print-layouts

I am using natural earth for qgis 3.0. I have rule based layers for 10m_admin_0m_maps_unit to show only a certain number of countries in my Caribbean map. That now looks perfect when I am in the qgis, but when I switch to the layout view to build my map, the layers are gone.

I have looked for some tutorials and saw that I should do the following
click layer properties, then under rendering, select show all labels for this layer (including colliding labels).
I have done this and refreshed my layout (the map is not locked), but the labels still do not appear.

I see that I can manually add the country names, but is there a way to get the selected names of this layer to show up on the layout map?

Comment: what rule do you use in QGIS to show the countrynames?

Comment: I used in Properties --> Label --> Rendering --> Show Label.  

"Edit..." and added the expression

"name" in ( 'Venezuela' , 'Cuba' , 'Mexico' )

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out. I didn't realise that although I had selected show all labels, 'scale dependent visibility' was selected and as a result, my labels were not visible in layout. After unselecting and refreshing the view, the country names appeared.